# How can I list only modules which need an update?

Tags: drush

Drush 8.1.9 & Drupal 7.53.
What I'm looking for is a command like `drush ups` but without all the modules that are `[OK]` – so when used with an alias of several sites I don't have to scroll through loads. So all I get is:

```
aliasname     
Name                               Installed Version  Proposed version  Message          
     Metatag (metatag)                  7.x-1.19           7.x-1.20          Update available 
     Views Slideshow (views_slideshow)  7.x-3.4            7.x-3.5           Update available
```

I found `drush vset update_check_disabled 1 -y && drush -n -p up` – it works but here's a sample output, which is not what I want.

```
media_ckeditormedia_ckeditormedia_ckeditor
views_slideshowmedia_ckeditor
```

I also want the version info. Is there anything I can do to get a list of all modules which need an update including the version info?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Drush puts that [ok] information out on stderr. So you can actually just dump that by using:

```
drush ups 2>/dev/null
```

which for me gave:

```
 $ drush ups 2>/dev/null
 Name    Installed Version  Proposed version  Message
 Drupal  8.2.5              8.2.6             Update available
```

Answer (score 7):

Consider using '**grep**'. It's not exactly a drush-specific command but will get the job done.

```
drush ups | grep 'Update available'
```

This command will return all lines that contain the phrase 'Update available'.

Comment: Yep, this is one way. For the uninitiated - this will pipe the output of drush ups to grep, which will filter by "Update available"

Comment: Just tried this, but I still see all the 'Checking available updates... [OK]' ones above. What it does do is get rid of the 'Name' 'Installed version' column headings above the ones that need updates, so looks like it works on the results rather than the part where drush is checking each module.

Comment: yeah, it processes the output from the tool itself. you can also consider custom drush commands. https://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-create-drush-command/

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a go - might wait till I've learned more drush basics first :)

Answer (score 7):

In a Drupal 8 project it's better to list updates using `composer`:

```
composer outdated 'drupal/*'
```

Comment: This is a great command. Its a shame the error when running `drush ups` doesn't suggest this as the alternative.

Answer (score 6):

If your site is built with Composer you can use [`drush pm:security`](https://www.drush.org/commands/10.x/pm_security/).

> Check Drupal Composer packages for pending security updates.
>
> This uses the [Drupal security advisories package](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-security-advisories) to determine if
> updates are available.

This will give you the following sample output:

> ```
> +-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
> | Name        | Installed Version | Suggested version |
> +-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
> | drupal/core | 8.6.7             | 8.6.10            |
> +-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Using [`drush pm:security`](https://www.drush.org/commands/10.x/pm_security/), you can automatically update your website using the BASH code:

```bash
SECURITY_UPDATES=$(drush pm:security --field=name | tr '\n' ' ')
SECURITY_UPDATES=${SECURITY_UPDATES//drupal\/core/drupal\/core-recommended}
      
composer update $SECURITY_UPDATES --with-dependencies
```